# How can I parallelize a for loop that saves rdd into cassandra in spark with java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have streaming RDD and applied java POJO on it, now have inputRDD, this contains id,.. other details. I want groupby/filterby id then each rdd should save in their own DB. I have tried and code working with for loop, but if this need to happen in spark parallel processing. any help appreciated.

```
 messages.transform(this::getClass).foreachRDD(inputRDD -> {
    List<String> idList = inputRDD.map(ClassObject::getEmpid).distinct().collect();
    for (String id : idList){
    String EmpName = EmpCache.getEmpNameFor(id).toLowerCase();    
    inputRDD.filter(f -> f.getEmpid().equals(id));

    javaFunctions(inputRDD).writerBuilder(in_EmpName , tableName, mapToRow(agg)).saveToCassandra();
    }
}
```

Comment: @jaimin03 can you post your answer again?